# nginx regex not behaving as expected when matching query string

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I have an nginx server that sits in front of my site. It is used to direct the public page requests to varnish cache and any other request straight to HA Proxy. For the public part, I am adding trailing slashes using a 301 redirect for SEO purposes.

This is my location block:

```
location ~* ^((?!api|dashio|socket.io|pagespeed)[^.\?])*[^/]$ {
    return 301 $scheme://$host$request_uri/;
}
```

1) `(?!api|dashio|socket.io|pagespeed)`
This part is a negative lookahead that will not match if any of the specified strings are found.

2) `(...[^.\?])*`
This part captures any character that is not a `.` or a `?`

3) `[^/]$`
Finally, this part matches any string that doesn't end in a slash

All together this should match any url that doesn't contain `api`, `dashio`, `socket.io`, `pagespeed`, a `.` or a `?`. Strangely, everything works perfectly except from the `?` part to not break query strings.

When I put the regex into http://www.regexr.com/ and check it against `/test?test=1234`, it correctly doesn't match the string but Nginx still matches it.

If anyone has any ideas, they would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what you trying to match doesn't contain parameters. URI only.

Comment: And you should escape dots by the way

Answer (score 0):

See https://serverfault.com/questions/237517/nginx-query-keyword-matching-in-location.

> This is not possible as locations will only match against the URI
>   without query parameters. You'll need to use an if inside the location
>   along with http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24arg_PARAMETER
>
> if ($is_args)
>   {
>       break; 
>   }

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I tried this but when it get's into the if statement and hits the `break`, I get an Nginx 404. The request never gets to the back end.